# Angular Form problem with matDatepickerMax validation

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm facing the following problem, maybe some of you know how to solve it.
I have a formGroup with different fields, one of them is a date field with a mat date picker.
I'm changing programmatically the [max] property of the date picker input but the form is validating always with the first value in  the max property and I'm receiving the error "matDatepickerMax".
Any idea, As I see the input is working fine and the max value is updated correctly, but the formgroup is validating always with the old value.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you create a Stackblitz example showing your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Franco, when you create a validator, the value you pass is the value in the moment. fool example

```
data={name:'one'}
form=new FormGroup({
   name:new FormControl(data.name)
   control:new FormControl('',this.foolValidator(data.name))
})

foolValidator(name:string)
{
    //only gives error if control.value is "one"
    
    return (control)=>{
       return control.value==name?{repeat:true}:null
    }
}
```

If you want take account a variable you can "bind" the validator

```
data={name:'one'}
form=new FormGroup({
   name:new FormControl(data.name)
   control:new FormControl('',this.foolValidator().bind(this))
})

foolValidator()
{
    return (control)=>{
       return control.value==this.form.get('name').value?{repeat:true}:null
    }
}
```

Or create a custom validator like

```
foolValidator()
{
    return (control)=>{
       const form=control.parent;
       if (form)
       {
          const name=form.get('name')
          return name && control.value==name.value?{repeat:true}:null
       }
    }
}
```

In this last case, don't forget, when change "name", make an `form.get('control').updateValueAndValidity`